# Your kernel does not support pids limit capabilities or the cgroup is not mounted. PIDs limit discarded

Tags: podman

I am getting following error when I try to test Podman

```
sudo podman run hello-world
Your kernel does not support pids limit capabilities or the cgroup is not mounted. PIDs limit discarded.
WARN[0000] cannot create a new network namespace: "permission denied"
ERRO[0000] error unmounting /var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/de53353b133ffc4eeec2755dc0e349f635a2a78330e54fd80b3c80de4c2d4872/merged: invalid argument
ERRO[0000] Error preparing container 7ce778ea27e0e2b9cb783e80b2b2ff8badd56aa3c600cea86f48aa9251fcf802: error creating network namespace for container 7ce778ea27e0e2b9cb783e80b2b2ff8badd56aa3c600cea86f48aa9251fcf802: failed to create namespace: permission denied
Error: error mounting storage for container 7ce778ea27e0e2b9cb783e80b2b2ff8badd56aa3c600cea86f48aa9251fcf802: error creating overlay mount to /var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/de53353b133ffc4eeec2755dc0e349f635a2a78330e54fd80b3c80de4c2d4872/merged, mount_data="nodev,metacopy=on,lowerdir=/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/l/7ISSZSFHCYBZ6SVTG2RLCE5BUS,upperdir=/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/de53353b133ffc4eeec2755dc0e349f635a2a78330e54fd80b3c80de4c2d4872/diff,workdir=/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/de53353b133ffc4eeec2755dc0e349f635a2a78330e54fd80b3c80de4c2d4872/work": invalid argument
```

I think my cgroup is mounted properly see below, I may be missing stuff here as I an entirely new here

```
mount | grep -i cgroup
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
```

Answer (score 0):

The right mount list is:

```sh
[root@DESKTOP-6RJ]# mount | grep -i cgroup
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=755)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma)
```

My root cause: **CPU visualization** is not enabled in BIOS.

Comment: I  have to reinstall the ubuntu,  after enable CPU visualization and reinstall,  the cgroups is mounted right.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I was using ubuntu 20.04 LTS on wsl in windows server 2019. This issue was due to wsl1 since windows server 2019 does not support wsl2. So instead of using podman I switched to docker engine from DockerMSFTProvider. But this docker version also does not work on linux containers again due to lack of wsl2 support. So I used LCOW(Linux containers on Windows Server) to run linux containers on windows and for this I didn't even need to install wsl.
See this blog to setup docker EE on LCOW
https://medium.com/@fizaashraf37/run-docker-linux-containers-on-windows-server-2019-lcow-step-by-step-guide-452cf6bf3180